# Commenting out code does not work properly in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to able to comment or uncomment multiple lines of code by pressing ctrl+/

```py
# x = 10 
# print(x)
```

But now I press ctrl+/, it becomes the following:

```py
...
```

I tried to search for solution online, and I believe it is because the Windows shortcut somehow overwrite the shortcut in VS code. But I cannot find a solution.

I tried:

1.Reset the shortcut

2.Reinstall VS code

They don't work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all see which keyboard layout you are using on your System. Change the Keyboard layout to US-Keyboard if US keyboard is not selected.

If it is US keyboard then,

The shortcut key might have changed.

You can edit your preferences on VS code.

1. Goto File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search for Toggle Line Comments.
3. Click on edit icon and press your desired shortcut key

It could also be caused due to the same key bindings for shortcuts.The Keyboard Shortcuts editor has a context menu command Show Same Keybindings, which will filter the keybindings based on a keyboard shortcut to display conflicts. To view same key bindings follow the above steps till Step 3.
Now right click on the Toggle Line commands and click Show same key bindings.

Comment: Not working in Linux Mint

Comment: @thinkerBOB conflict in key binding is possible. remove them

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this problem before. You should press `shift` key to switch back to type English and try again.

Comment: I lost 45 mins of time on this until I saw your comment. haha

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what language you are programming.
But if you want to type # character you can hold down shift key and press number 3 on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you might just have another keyboard layout. Check the menu to see which shortcut you need to press. For example, `Toggle line comment` is `Ctrl+#` here:

[image]

*(By mistake, I had thought at first that I can handle the shortcuts only if I stick to the US-ENG keyboard layout to have `Ctrl+/` back. Not needed; check your menu in the other layout.)*

Answer (score 0):

go to keyboard short cuts
search for toggle line comment

check when expression in  when column

right click on the when expression and edit and paste "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings, find keyboard on Application/Keyboard change Keyboard: Dispatch code to keyCode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).